# change userlevel on button click in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I am trying to update `userlevel` when click on button. i have a page where it will display all users there i have change level button.by default every user will be in  normal level(means 3) so when i click on a button it has to change to 5(lead
) and if i click again it has to change to 9(admin)

here is my  view page code:

```
  <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <form method="post" class="change_userlevel" action="" onclick="getConfirmation(9);">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $user->id; ?>">
                                        <button type="submit"   class="widget-icon" name="login"><span class='icon-arrow-up'></span></button>
                                    </form>
                                      </div>
<td>
                                    <?php
                                    if($usertype==9)
                                    {
                                      echo 'Admin';
                                    }
                                    elseif($usertype==5)
                                    {
                                        echo 'Teamlead';
                                    }
                                    else
                                     {
                                       echo 'Normal';  
                                     }
                                    ?>
                                 </td>
```

Here is my script code with ajax:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
function getConfirmation(id){
$.ajax({
        url: "User/change_status",
        type: "post",
        data: id,
        success: function (response) {
         location.reload();              

        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Here is my controller code method `change_status`:

```
   function  change_status(){
$id = $this->input->post('id');
$status = $this->db->query("select userlevel from users where id=9")->row()->userlevel;
if($status==3){
    $status = 5;
} else {
    $status = 9;
}
$data=array('userlevel'=>$status);
$this->db->where('id','id');
$this->db->update('users',$data);
}
```

I dont know where i have done mistake it is not working.

can anyone help me how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: should be like  `data: {'id' : id}` in your ajax

Comment: i have changed but still  its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Your `ajax` code should be like this :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function getConfirmation(id)
  {
    if (id != '')
    {
        $.ajax({
          url: "<?=site_url('User/change_status');?>",
          type: "post",
          data: {'id' : id},
          success: function (response) {
            alert('success');
           //location.reload();              
          }
      });
    }

}
</script>
```

Your method `change_status` should be like this :

```
function  change_status()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    $status = $this->db->select('userlevel')->where('id', $id)->get('users')->row()->userlevel;
    if($status == 3)
    {
        $status = 5;
    } else 
    {
        $status = 9;
    }
    $data = array('userlevel' => $status);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('users',$data);
    echo TRUE;exit;
}
```

Comment: i have updated your code so when i click on button it is giving success alert but its not updating userlevel value in db

Comment: pls see my updated answers for that and let me know its working for you

Comment: yeah its working and can you please tell me how to pass id dynamically in to getconfirmation in onclick="getConfirmation(9);

Comment: u can do something like this : `getConfirmation('<?=$user->id;?>')`

Comment: is there any possibility to show the userlevel name instaed of success alert for ex: if i click on normal level when it is gogint o change to lead i need to display alert like changing to lead

Comment: u can echo `userlevel name` instead of `true` in your controller method

Comment: if i echio in controller will it display as alert?

Comment: yes just try with name or id it will show u as an alert but in ajax do like this :  `alert(response);`

Comment: i can put only one one echo right like echo 'teamlead' ;after team lead update i want to change it to admin;